# Создание цикла для Qtreewidgetitem

Tags: qt, ini

Доброго времени суток. Есть проблема с созданием корректного цикла для отслеживания изменения значения в QTreewidgetItem. Собственно необходимо реализовать слот handler при нажатии на кнопку сканируются все значения в колонке(3) и сохраняются в ini файл.

```
void sw_IKGM_settings::handler_pb_save_changes_to_ini()
{

QTreeWidgetItem* pitem;
QStringList mylist;
int i = 0;

// sw_tree_item_my - структура, tc - QList структур
foreach(sw_tree_item_t my, tc) 
{
   my = tc.at(i);
   QString str = my.item->text(3)
   str = mylist.at(i);
}
```

При выполнении программа некорректно завершается. Можно достать последний элемент листа с помощью функции .last() но мне нужно узнать все измененные значения а не одно.

Comment: Цикл странный в me и так передается значение из списка, однако на каждой итерации вы переписываете его значением первого элемента цикла.
Также, вы обращаетесь к первому элементу mylist, который всегда пустой. В `tc` находятся все измененные элементы? Или их еще нужно определить?

Comment: В tc лежат все элементы которые мы считываем из ini файла и потом помещаем на widget. Предполагалось что необходимо перебирать каждый элемент из контейнера и по итератору каждый четвертый заменять тем значением, которое считывается из widget, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку сохранить значения.

Comment: а почему нельзя просто сохранить все значения? Их так много, чтобы сохранять все?

Comment: Таковы условия поставленной задачи, остальные поля не редактируются - редактируется только одно поле значения. Хотя в целом да можно было сделать, что бы каждый раз пересохраняло полностью весь ини файл собственно в итоге я так и сделал - так как стандартный QSettings отвратительно работает со спец символами и [] он понимал только как %5B %5D.

Comment: Я бы вообще не сохранял таблицы и деревья в ini формате :) Лучше xml или json. Т.е. вам нужно только пройтись по строкам таблицы и сравнить текущие значения с значениями из tc. А что дальше будете делать с этим уже по тз )

Comment: благодарю за совет ;) учту на будущее.